# How add a html template as loading screen in AngularJS untill http response is recieved?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

My project architecture is in this way .. I have a django-rest-api (api) in a django project and normal django app with TemplateView's , In django app templates I use both django template tags and angularJs tags and I differentiate them using {% verbaitm %} tag. I want to know the best way to show loading page .

NOTE :I have an issue in here , I load both angularJS Tags and Django Template tags in my project so i am not able to hide django template tags here, and show loading screen.

Comment: I have an issue in here , I load both angularJS Tags and Django Template tags in my project so i am not able to django template tags here, and shpw loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not worth making/loading an entire page for this. If you are waiting on an ajax call response, before you send the request you could pop some sort of loading overlay with the same Javascript you are creating the AJAX request with. Once you receive the response, use the success method to take down your loading 
overlay.

Answer (score -1):

Check [cfpLoadingBar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).

It is lovely and flexible. You can even ignore the loading for some particular requests.